# Finding how many pairs of numbers are in reach of a distance D in a sequence of integers

Tags: c, algorithm

Let's have an increasing sequence of distinct non-negative integers {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 12}. What's the fastest way of telling how many pairs are at most a distance let's say D = 3 from each other?

For example here it would be: [0, 2], [0, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 7], [7, 10], [10, 12], so 8.

My shot at this:

```
int arr[] = {0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 12};
int arrLength = 7;
int k = 1;
int D = 3;
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrLength;) {
    if (i + k < arrLength && arr[i + k] - arr[i] <= D) {
            sum++;
            k++;
    }
    else {
        i++;
        k = 1;
    }
    
}

printf("Number of pairs: %d\n", sum);
```

It takes too much time for larger arrays. Is there any other way of exploiting the fact, that:

- The sequence is always increasing.
- There can't be two same numbers.
- We don't need to print out the exact pairs, just the number of them.
- The integers can't be negative.
- We could somehow share already computed pairs to other iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` clause is very pessimistic. You don't need to reset `k` to 1. It is obvious that `a[i+1]` forms the pair with all values in the `[i+2, i+k)` range. Consider a sliding window, along the lines of (untested)

```
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    while (i < arrLen) {
        while (j < arrlen && a[j] - a[i] <= D) {
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        sum += j - i;
        if (i == j) {
            j++;
        }
   }
```

with a linear time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by dynamic programming. If `M(n)` is number of specified pairs, we will have `M(n) = M(n-1) + number of  pairs of A[0..n-2] with A[n-1] which have less than D`. To find the last part of the recursion, it can be computed by `log(n)` as they are sorted. Hence, the time complexity of this algorithm is `T(n) = T(n-1) + log(n) = O(n log(n))`.